# Get two pages instead of one in print preview despite explicitly setting page + div heights on CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

In the following code, I am hardcoding the height of a lone `div` element to 29.7 cm and the page height to 29.7 cm.

## HTML

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0.2cm solid red;
    height: 29.7cm;
    width: calc(0.5 * 21.0cm);
}

@page {
    size: 21.0cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 0cm;
}
```

Why is it that when I print-preview the page on Chrome I get 2 pages instead of 1 page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can see the overspill better in Firefox than Edge where the page is simply truncated, and the issue is exacerbated when using different versions or brands of browsers since the underlying conversions often vary depending on content.
[image]
I generally have to round SVG outputs downwards more than "normal" divisions

How to ensure it fits is over-ride the metric with pixels

[image]
[image]

If we save the pre-render from the browser we see from the HTML editor it applied a local style over-ride

```
</head>
<body>
    <div style="
    height: 1122px;
"></div>
</body></html>
```

Ok so what is needed for FireFox ? and here we see they use a totally different scalar !! so one div height does not fit all browsers in all cases!

[image]

Can we use one css for both, yes but beware there be dragons of other differences.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<style>
 @media screen, print { @page { margin: 0; size: 794px 1122.5px !important; } body { margin: 0px; } } 
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 7px solid red;
    width: 397px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 1108px !important;"> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>FireFox & Edge</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have set the height of your `div` to 29.7cm and also add a border of 0.2cm meaning the total height of the box becomes `29.7cm (content) + 0.2cm (top border) + 0.2cm (bottom border)` = `30.1cm`.

Additionally you have set the page size using @page to 21.0cm by 29.7cm, meaning the maximum height of a single page to be 29.7cm.

Now The total height of the `div`: `30.1cm` is slightly larger than the `page height`: `29.7cm`, so when the browser prepares to print, it realizes that the content can't fit on a single page. As a result, the browser splits the content between two pages during the print-preview to make sure everything fits.

To prevent this, you need to adjust the height of the `div` so that it fits within the available page height while accounting for the borders and any other elements on the page. This ensures that the content can be displayed on a single page during print-preview.

I've reduced the height of `div` to 29.3cm which will now add up to `29.3cm (content) + 0.2cm (top border) + 0.2cm (bottom border)` = `29.7cm`.

If you want you can tweak this value. Hope it helped :)

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
    }

    /*div {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 0.2cm solid red;
        height: 29.7cm;
        width: calc(0.5 * 21.0cm);
    }*/
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 0.2cm solid red;
        height: 29.3cm; /* Adjusted height to account for borders */
        width: calc(0.5 * 21.0cm);
    }

    @page {
        size: 21.0cm 29.7cm;
        margin: 0cm;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using border-box sizing which should already account for the border dimensions, so I'm pretty sure your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, it results in a PDF where there is space between the bottom of the `div` border and the bottom edge of the page. This is to be expected because `border-box` sizing already accounts for the border widths.

Comment: So tweak the value to 29.65cm. Then you won't get any space b/w the bottom of `div` border and bottom edge of the page.

Comment: I'd rather not tweak the value. I would like to understand why it is happening in the first place.

Comment: The `border-box` sizing does account for the border dimensions. I believe that the behavior you're encountering is due to how browsers handle the rendering and pagination of content for print. I've no explanation other than this.

Comment: If `border-box` accounts for border dimensions, then why would one need to reduce the height or width of the `div` or tweak its value? Your answer contradicts your last comment. Please go back and review what `border-box` actually means: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#try_it

Comment: I experimented with your code a bit. When I set `display: block` instead of `inline-block`, with the height being `height: 29.7cm`, it was clearly visible that the div was overflowing from the page. Reducing height to `height: 29.65` with still `display: block`, it solved the issue, in fact the issue no longer persisted even with `display: inline-block`. I don't know what's the issue underneath and I believe the issue is due to how browsers handle the rendering and pagination of content for print. I'm still confused though why it is happening in the first place.